# Getting data from SQL Server using xpath

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xpath

I am trying to get some data in XML form from a database, and I have some success but I seem to be unable to filter it.

I have to cast because the data is stored as nvarchar

```
select 
    cast (questions.[Text] as xml)
        .query('/table/tbody/tr/td[@data-bm="cip_3_timeframe"]') as timeframe
from 
    ODQuestions 
where 
    QuestionType = 5
```

I do get information back. Some blank rows and some rows with the XML I want! So I tried to add a simple

```
select 
    cast(questions.[Text] as xml)
       .query('/table/tbody/tr/td[@data-bm="cip_3_timeframe"]') as timeframe
from 
    ODQuestions 
where 
    QuestionType = 5 and timeframe <> ''
```

and it seems timeframe is not a column.

I also tried

```
select 
    cast (questions.[Text] as xml) as timeframe,
    timeframe.query('/table/tbody/tr/td[@data-bm="cip_3_timeframe"]') 
from 
    ODQuestions 
where 
    QuestionType = 5 
    and timeframe.exists('/table/tbody/tr/td[@data-bm="cip_3_timeframe"]')
```

Similarly resulting in

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot find either column "timeframe" or the user-defined function or aggregate "timeframe.query", or the name is ambiguous.

Any clues on how to filter this data would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a test in the XPath predicate to filter out empty `td` elements:

```
select cast (questions.[Text] as xml)
  .query('/table/tbody/tr/td[@data-bm="cip_3_timeframe"][normalize-space()]') as timeframe
   from ODQuestions 
   where QuestionType = 5
```

`td[normalize-space()]` will filter out `td` elements that are empty or contain only whitespaces.

Comment: Hm I just get

```XQuery [query()]: There is no function '{http://www.w3.org/2004/07/xpath-functions}:normalize-space()'```

Answer (score 0):

Next time it would help to provide a (reduced) example of your XML, just enough to reproduce your issue and state the expected output.

If I get this correctly you want to avoid empty results. You can try one of these:

```
select A.Casted.query('/table/tbody/tr/td[@data-bm="cip_3_timeframe"]') as timeframe
from   ODQuestions q
cross apply
       (
          SELECT cast (q.[Text] as xml)
       ) A(Casted)
where 
    q.QuestionType = 5 
    AND A.Casted.exist('/table/tbody/tr/td[@data-bm="cip_3_timeframe"]')=1;
```

Or maybe something along this

```
select A.Casted.query('/table
                       /tbody
                       /tr
                       /td[not(empty(.)) and @data-bm="cip_3_timeframe"]') as timeframe
from   ODQuestions q 
cross apply
       (
          SELECT cast (q.[Text] as xml)
       ) A(Casted)
where 
    q.QuestionType = 5
```

Or something along this

```
select A.Casted.query('/table
                       /tbody
                       /tr[not(empty(/td/@data-bm))]
                       /td[@data-bm="cip_3_timeframe"]') as timeframe
from   ODQuestions q 
cross apply
       (
          SELECT cast (q.[Text] as xml)
       ) A(Casted)
where 
    q.QuestionType = 5
```